# Returning a const reference to set of an pair

Tags: c++, reference, return

I have two questions

1) How can I return a reference to a set which belongs to a pair?

I have this class:

```
class Test{
public:
  typedef int edge;
  const edge& getFirst() const { return doubleSet.first; }
  void add(i) { getFirst().insert(i); };
private:
   pair< set<edge>, set<edge> > doubleSet;
};
```

My compiler don't want to let me return the reference from getFirst due to conversion issue

2) I do not want it to be possible to change Test.doubleSet outside of the class, but I want to return a reference because of efficiency

Comment: for your second question: `edge& getFirst(){ return doubleSet.first; }` : make it constant `const edge& getFirst() const { return doubleSet.first; }`. For your first question, I'm not getting it. Can you [edit] your question?

Comment: I have to say that `doubleSet` just has the wrong ring to it. Every time I read it I expect  a `set<double>`

Comment: I don't think that a set defines the operations required to be a member of a set. How do you define "less-than" or "equal" for a set?

Comment: @ZanLynx, you don't. I think the OP misspoke and meant "*belongs to a* `pair`"

Comment: The first member of the pair is a `set<edge>`  , it does not make sense to bind `const edge&` to a whole set at once. Maybe you meant `getFirst()` to return `const set<edge>&` ?